# .NET Export to Excel - bug in IE?

Tags: .net, asp.net, internet-explorer, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a report into excel in vb.net.

everything works fine in Chrome and FF, but when i do it in IE, the active directory login pop up keeps coming up.

if i cancel it (like 4-5 times) the files saves just fine... why is it popping up> is there a way around it?

please see my code below:

```
 Protected Sub lnkExport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkExport.Click
        Dim ds As DataSet = cSource.FindSources(Session("uid"), True, txtID.Text )

        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        Dim filename As String = "AASD"
        ' first let's clean up the response.object
        response.Clear()
        response.Charset = ""

        ' set the response mime type for excel
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & filename & """")

        ' create a string writer
        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Using htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                ' instantiate a datagrid
                Dim dg As New DataGrid()
                dg.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                dg.DataBind()
                dg.RenderControl(htw)
                response.Write(sw.ToString())
                response.[End]()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: What version of IE are you running? I had a similar problem and it magically went away when I installed the latest version...

Comment: Can you post the code used to send the excel sheet to the browser?

Comment: 8.. but the users also use 8. i'll try to download 9 and see if it goes away. maybe i'll put a disclaimer on the site or something... if there's no other way to fix this.

Comment: @Robert - please see my code above... i just edited my message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it got fixed by writing out the data to excel, cell by cell in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a security issue in IE8/9.  Try adding the host to the "Trusted sites" on the Security tab of IE Options.  You can also try holding down your left shift key while trying to download the spreadsheet.